# Оптимизация работы парсера

Tags: php, парсер

Здравствуйте.

Допустим, есть сайт, который парсит информацию с 3х+ разных сайтов режиме нон-стоп, то есть, человек, например, заходит на сайт, вводит в поиске что-либо, выбирает, с какого сайта пойдет поиск, и, соответственно, ему выводит результат.

Собственно, вопрос: **сильная ли будет нагрузка**, если сайт посещают много народу? Есть ли какие-то идеи по оптимизации? Информация из поиска не является статичной и может измениться в любой момент.

Comment: кешировать, кешировать и ещё раз кешировать!

> сильная ли будет нагрузка

вначале нагрузка будет пропорциональная кол-ву людей, а когда ресурсы сервера кончатся, тогда... ну Вы поняли, нет смысла измерять нагрузку.

Comment: @KoVadim, хм, а как возможно закешировать более 5 миллионов результатов? Куда, как?

Comment: 5 миллионов? Вы уже посчитали?

Никто не обязывает хранить 5 миллионов результатов. Можно хранить немножко. например, только 10 тысяч.

Comment: @KoVadim, а как и где хранить такой кэш, как из него брать информацию, как обновлять (все результаты являются динамическими и могут быть изменены в любое время)?

Comment: memcache/redis/mongo

Как по мне, то redis может оказаться хорошим средством, если правильно приготовить.

Comment: @KoVadim, как раз вчера читал про memcache. Скажите пожалуйста, я правильно понимаю? Нужно, если данные в кэш еще не забиты, то записывать их на, допустим, 10 дней, если же существуют, то просто считывать из кэша? И сколько по времени лучше хранить информацию, например, описание результата? И можно ли записать HTML-разметку туда?

Comment: советовать что то для абстрактной задачи - плохое дело.

какие то данные хранятся долго, какие то немножко. Все очень сильно зависит от конкретной задачи.

html разметку? а чем она отличается от обычного текста? а так как ничем, то да, конечно можно.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за ответы, буду думать.